# the @Mock and @InjectMocks annotations don't work

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

- rest

```java
@RestController
public class StackOverFlowController {


    private StackOverFlowService service;

    @Autowired
    public StackOverFlowController(
            @Qualifier(value = "stackOverFlowServiceImpl")
            StackOverFlowService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @RequestMapping("api/stackoverflow")
    public List<StackOverFlowDto> getListOfProviders() throws URISyntaxException {

        List<StackOverFlowDto> allSites = service.getAllSites();

        return allSites;
    }
}
```

- service

```java
public interface StackOverFlowService {
    List<StackOverFlowDto> getAllSites() throws URISyntaxException;

    List<StackOverFlowDto> getAllSitesByTitle(String title) throws URISyntaxException;
}
```

- pom.xml

```xml
 <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${version.mapstruct}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>29.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

- test

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class StackOverFlowControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private StackOverFlowService service ;

    @InjectMocks
    private StackOverFlowController controller;


    @Test
    public void getListOfProviders() throws URISyntaxException {
        List<StackOverFlowDto> allSites = service.getAllSites();

        when(service.getAllSites()).thenReturn(ImmutableList.of());
        List<StackOverFlowDto> listOfProviders = controller.getListOfProviders();
        verify(service).getAllSites();

    }
}
```

I can create an mock-object this way: :

```java
private StackOverFlowService service =  Mockito.mock(StackOverFlowService.class);
```

**update 1**

[image]

**update 2**

Wnen I have done this:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(StackOverFlowController.class)
public class StackOverFlowControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private StackOverFlowService service;

    @InjectMocks
     StackOverFlowController controller;


    @Test
    public void getListOfProviders() throws URISyntaxException {
        List<StackOverFlowDto> allSites = service.getAllSites();

        when(service.getAllSites()).thenReturn(ImmutableList.of());
        List<StackOverFlowDto> listOfProviders = controller.getListOfProviders();
        verify(service).getAllSites();

    }
}
```

I got an error:

> PM org.junit.vintage.engine.descriptor.RunnerTestDescriptor warnAboutUnfilterableRunner WARNING: Runner
> org.junit.internal.runners.ErrorReportingRunner (used on class
> com.spring.mongo.web.contollers.stackoverflow.StackOverFlowControllerTest)
> does not support filtering and will therefore be run completely.
> org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class
> 'com.spring.mongo.web.contollers.stackoverflow.StackOverFlowControllerTest':
>
> 1. No runnable methods

[image]

where is the method get() from ?

**update 3**

This the test was performed:

```java
@WebMvcTest(StackOverFlowController.class)
public class StackOverFlowControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private StackOverFlowService service;

    @MockBean
    private StackOverFlowController controller;

    @Test
    public void getListOfProviders() throws Exception {

        when(service.getAllSites()).thenReturn(ImmutableList.of());
        List<StackOverFlowDto> listOfProviders = controller.getListOfProviders();
        assertNotNull(listOfProviders);

   }
}
```

But I don't see the point. I don't get any data:

```java
 List<StackOverFlowDto> listOfProviders = controller.getListOfProviders();
```

- But here I should get a collection of elements, but I get 0

**Update 4**

It is my the understanding:

```java
when(service.getAllSites()).thenReturn(ImmutableList.of());
```

We test a controller. We don't need below layers. We need to validate that the method

- getListOfProviders()
  of a contoller is called.
  So,
- service.getAllSites()
  here we point Mockito-object

```java
@MockBean
    private StackOverFlowService service;
```

This method should return some sort of collection.

```java
thenReturn(ImmutableList.of())
```

it should return empty collection.

Why ?

I don't understand this.

```java
List<StackOverFlowDto> listOfProviders = controller.getListOfProviders();
```

What is it for?

**Update 5**

```java
    @Test
    public void getListOfProviders() throws Exception {

        when(service.getAllSites()).thenReturn(ImmutableList.of());
        List<StackOverFlowDto> listOfProviders = controller.getListOfProviders();
        assertNotNull(listOfProviders);

        verify(service).getAllSites();
    }
```

- verify(service).getAllSites();
  This should validate that the method **getAllSites()**  from interface StackOverFlowService (from its implemetation), will call...

But Again I got errors:

> Wanted but not invoked:
> com.spring.mongo.service.read.stackoverflow.StackOverFlowService#0
> bean.getAllSites();
> -> at com.spring.mongo.web.contollers.stackoverflow.StackOverFlowControllerTest.getListOfProviders(StackOverFlowControllerTest.java:38)
> Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
>
> Wanted but not invoked:
> com.spring.mongo.service.read.stackoverflow.StackOverFlowService#0
> bean.getAllSites();
> -> at com.spring.mongo.web.contollers.stackoverflow.StackOverFlowControllerTest.getListOfProviders(StackOverFlowControllerTest.java:38)
> Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Why ?

**Update 6**

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringMongoApplication.class})
@WebMvcTest(StackOverFlowController.class)
class StackOverFlowControllerTestUnit {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private StackOverFlowService service;

    @MockBean
    private StackOverFlowController controller;

    @Test
    void getListOfProviders() throws Exception {

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder =
                MockMvcRequestBuilders
                        .get("/api/stackoverflow")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.id").exists())
                .andDo(print());

    }
}
```

Here beans is created, but i don't result into json...

```java
 .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.sites").exists())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.sites[*].id").isNotEmpty());
```

**Update_7**

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringMongoApplication.class})
@WebMvcTest(StackOverFlowController.class)
public class StackOverFlowControllerTestFromForum {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private StackOverFlowService service;

    @InjectMocks
    private StackOverFlowController controller;

   @Test
   public void getListOfProviders() throws Exception {

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder =
                MockMvcRequestBuilders
                        .get("/api/stackoverflow")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

- In this version of the code, all beans are initialized without errors.
  **@InjectMocks** - It is work also.

  Normal integration testing offered by Spring simply creates objects
  as if the application were running in production. I still don't
  understand what Mock-objects are for.

Here any ideas is finished.
I don't understand why it dosen't work.

Сan someone explain the idea of @Mock and @InjectMocks annotations working in relation to this example ?
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You are using the `SpringRUnner` and not the `MockitoJUnitRunner` as you posted in your code. The screenshot doesn't match the code you wrote, the thing you wrote is correct, the one in your screenshot isn't.

Comment: I tried difference things.

Comment: If you want to use `@Mock` etc. you need the `MOckitoJunitRunner` else the annotations don't do anything.

Comment: What versions are you using? Spring Boot version, Mockito, JUnit?

Comment: SpringBoot - 2.3.2.RELEASE , JUnit 5

Comment: mockito is from org.springframework.boot.test.mock.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` instead of `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`, it should work. SpringRunner will help with Dependency Injection of the mocks.

Edit:

Try with the code below:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringMongoApplication.class})
@WebMvcTest(StackOverFlowController.class)
public class StackOverFlowControllerTestUnit {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private StackOverFlowService service;

    @Test
    void getListOfProviders() throws Exception {

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder =
                MockMvcRequestBuilders
                        .get("/api/stackoverflow")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
                // .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.id").exists())
                // .andDo(print());

    }
}
```

Try going step by step. If the above works then maybe you can go for the json path verification

Comment: I overlooked the face that you are trying to test a controller. Maybe you can try @WebMvcTest(StackOverFlowController.class)

For your reference, check the example @ my github:https://github.com/kdsalvy/Spring-Boot/blob/master/SpringFrameworksIntegrated/src/test/java/mini/project/spring/web/controller/BookControllerTest.java

Comment: I added above attempts to follow your advice

Comment: I hope you still have the `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` annotation

Comment: I think you need to call it by creating an object of type RequestBuilder. `RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/stackoverflow")` and pass the same as an argument to `mockMvc.perform(request)`

Comment: I tried the solution that you offered (see above, 'update 6')

Comment: You shouldn't mock the Controller itself, only mocking the service will do. In my example ResourceAssembler is another service.

Comment: I don't use   private StackOverFlowController controller; I will delete. I can't validate andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.sites").exists()) , What is an error there?

Comment: may be will you write an example ?

Comment: can you explain this : jsonPath("$.id") - It bit code does't work for me (.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.id").exists())).

Comment: @InjectMocks
    private StackOverFlowController controller; - It bit code gives an errors

Comment: 1. It should be : public class.  2.   It should be : public void name_some_method(). 3. In need use an annotation   @MockBean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219238/discussion-between-saurabh-kedia-and-skyho).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the controller test to be the same like any other unit test case class then use spring for running tests using annotation `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` .Since you are writing the unit test case for the controller , use the  test method like below.You just need to mock the service call and call the controller method or more appropriately hit it via mock mvc :

```
@Test
public void getListOfProviders() throws URISyntaxException {
    when(service.getAllSites()).thenReturn(ImmutableList.of());
    List<StackOverFlowDto> listOfProviders = controller.getListOfProviders();
    assertNotNull(listOfProviders);
}
```

But if you want it to be the right way then :

```
@WebMvcTest
public class StackOverFlowControllerTest {
    
    @Mock
    private StackOverFlowService service ;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void getListOfProviders() throws URISyntaxException {
        when(service.getAllSites()).thenReturn(ImmutableList.of());
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("api/stackoverflow")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());

    }
}
```

If you are having issues ith `@WebMvcTest` it means springboot is having trouble setting up the test env because of project structure or annotation on main application class that might be causing issues for test setup so in that case try setting up an entire application context like in an integration test (a bit tedious and unnecessary ) by using the `@SpringBootTest` annotation instead.

Official doc [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/).

Comment: I added above attempts to follow your advice